How can I order or sort many distributions, then summarize the "quantiles" of this ordered list?
What are the best practices for sorting a large number of distributions? What are some of the pros and cons of different ways to do this?
Let's say I am working with Likert responses to a survey question on a 1 to 5 scale. (For example: Strongly Disagree; Disagree; Neutral; Agree; and Strongly Agree. Or another example: Poor; Fair; Good; Very Good; Excellent.) But I want to compare them as batches of responses, not at the level of individual responses.
For example, imagine the online ratings for a product, from 1 to 5 stars: How can I sort a long list of products, each with its own distribution of ratings?
I know there's no single best way to define this sort order, and it's a matter of judgment as to which ordering is best for the task. For example, if one product got ten 1-star ratings and ten 5-stars, while another got twenty 3-stars, neither is unambiguously better. But if I had to order these (and 100s of other product-rating distributions), what are my options?
I could sort by means: Represent the 5 Likert scale values with numbers 1 through 5, take an average for each batch, and sort by the averages. But this ignores the fact that the difference between 1 and 2 may be very different than the difference between 4 and 5, etc.
I could also sort by weighted means by assigning greater weight to some values than others (e.g. weighing 5s higher than 4s etc). For my application, I'd rather avoid any method that needs us to choose such weights; it would require stakeholder buy-in and consensus that will be hard to achieve.
Or I could sort by proportions above/below some threshold: For example, calculate the proportion of ratings that were 4 or higher for each batch, then sort by these proportions. This seems better, but it still depends on the threshold I chose.
I've also heard of lexicographic dominance: First do a partial sort by the proportion of 5s. Then if some have an equal proportion of 5s, sort that subgroup by their proportion of 4s. And so on. This seems even better, but I might be missing some obvious downsides to this approach.
What are some other ways to define a total order on such distributions? What are their pros and cons?

(PS -- The closest question I've found on this site is here. But it's focused on one specific approach, and the consensus seems to be that this isn't a great approach. I am curious to know what other alternatives are out there.)
(PPS -- Sorry if I've missed other questions/answers around this; I can't figure out the right keywords to search for. I have tried searching for best practices regarding "stochastic order" or "stochastic dominance," but most of the search results I've found are about partial orders. For my application, I need to choose a total order.)
(PPPS -- The orderings listed above may be strongly affected by small sample sizes. For this question, assume all of the batches have the same sample size, so the focus is just on the ordering/sorting. I'm aware that there are other tools, like Bayesian rating, that could help make it fairer to compare small batches with large batches; but that's not what I'm asking about here.)

If it helps, what I ultimately want to do is choose some kind of "quantiles" for these distributions. For example: what's a "median" distribution of product rating scores? What are the 10th and 90th "percentiles," so we can get a rough sense of "it's not unusual to see score distributions that look this bad / this good"?
One way is to start with a total order on the distributions, and then use the ones that are 10, 50, and 90% of the way along the ranked list as examples / exemplars.
But perhaps there's some other way to select or summarize the distributions which are "low but not the lowest" and "typical" and "high but not the highest," without actually sorting all of the distributions first. I'm actually OK with showing several exemplars at each percentile, so an ordering with ties could be OK if the "tied" groups aren't too large. I'd love to hear other ideas.

Despite what many people say or preach, sorting by means often works quite well. To those who say that only sorting by medians makes sense, I want to ask "Do you really regard 1 2 2 2 2 and 2 2 2 3 5 as equivalent?"

@NickCox Thanks! I agree with you about sorting by medians -- I didn't even mention that option in my questions, for exactly the reason that you illustrated.

Quite; but it's widely preached dogma that only medians are defensible summaries of the level of ordinal data.

Isn't this because the finite sample mean estimator has a low break down point of 1/n https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics compared to 0.5 for the median estimator?

the breakdown point of the mean is not that low in a sample constrained between 0 and 5. Depending on the distribution and sample, the median could make bigger jumps than the mean for one or a few outliers.

Throughout the lifetime of this site, I have repeatedly and consistently recommended MAVT as essentially the most applicable, disciplined, and theoretically rigorous approach to such ranking problems, so I won't repeat myself here.  I have studied and applied this technique in various complex, real-world situations and find its principles and methods always to be helpful. From this perspective, every answer here is arbitrary.

@whuber From your first source: "[...] MAVT is based on point estimates [...]". Does that include quantiles, in your experience? Personally, I have gone in a direction that focuses on measure theory and order theory, but I feel I should learn more about the work that has already been done out there. I could just be reinventing wheels.

@Galen MAVT can be extended using utility theory, but that would make it exceptionally complicated.  Regardless, the basic ideas and theorems apply even to distributions -- and have profound implications for how one even expresses the numbers in those distributions.

@whuber Sounds exciting. I'll see if I can get my hands on that book, or something else covering MAVT. Thanks!

The starting point for this in my view is always what the meaning and background of the data is, and particularly how the resulting ordering will be used. Different approaches will treat certain cases in a different way, and in order to know what is better in your situation you need to ask which of the options is preferable in terms of the consequences in your situation and why. (And if that's not clear, the answer may well be "it doesn't matter, any half reasonable looking thing will be OK".)

Incidentally? This (Given your PPS not so) related blog post on the topic came up on hn today: https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

@whuber Thanks for the suggestion of MAVT. I will take a closer look.

@jan-glx The so-called "correct solution" in that blog (using lower confidence limits to compare ratings) is based on a misinterpretation of confidence intervals and can be just as bad or even worse than the other approaches.

@whuber oh no, I skipped over the lines like "confidence level: pick 0.95 to have a 95% chance that your lower bound is correct" and failed to notice that that that blog post was discussed in the linked question and questions linked to it already. Given your comment on my comment I'll leave it here so that other can learn from my mistake :)
Aside, while any approach can be as bad or worse than any other without a clear problem formulation, I think that particular approach would do a much better job at filtering out the crap that doesn't even have fake-reviews on Amazon than the mean ...

Since you are comparing n-out-of-5-stars products ratings, I'd suggest you to do what everybody else is doing and simply compute the arithmetic means for each product.
By everybody else I mean Google, Apple, Amazon and so on, on their sites and apps.
Is the arithmetic mean always the best aggregation function?
Well, if your needs are particular enough, another statistic may be more useful. Risk adverse users for instance may prefer to avoid any product with any number of bad reviews, even if the average review is very good. Any single solution (total order) to this question has pros and cons and will fit better to the demands of some user than others. The arithmetic mean just happens to be the solution that works better for general purposes, by averaging all ratings and accounting of all nuances rather than focusing on narrower information like it's the case with lexicographic dominance, quantiles, or thresholding.
Stochastic dominance, on the other hand, offers a partial order. While it doesn't yield a full ranking, it does provide an ordering that any rational user would agree with, meaning that all users should prefer a product’s ratings when they stochastically dominate those of another product. In your case, you may decide to use stochastic dominance to find, for different percentage values p, some different products which ratings stochastically dominate at least a proportion p of the other ratings distributions.
In general, for your goal of selecting a illustrative set of ratings distributions, you could also look into clustering applied to ECDFs.

With stochastic ordering what would be the order for distributions 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2 vs 0.3,0,0,0,0.7 vs 0.2,0.2,0.2,0,0.4 ? The last dominates the first but not the second; what ranking does it get? I can imagine that there are a lot of these relationships where the partial order places many distributions as equal. This makes a ranking difficult.

you can't use stochastic dominance to create a full ranking, it's in my answer already. I see you suggested ELO for bridging that gap, it's quite an interesting approach, but in the end every total order is flawed in some way.

Ah, I see it a bit more clear now, you are not suggesting to create a ranking directly on the stochastic dominance relationships (which I found it difficult because you can have a and b not dominating one or the other and in some sence are equal, while c might diminate a but not b). So instead, there is an extra step by counting the number of other distributions that dominate the distribution x and the number of distributions that are dominated by the distribution x.

I wonder whether there is a relationship between the $p_x$, the proportion of the other ratings distributions that dominate $x$ and $r_x$, the proportion of the other ratings distributions that are dominated by $x$, such that $p_x > p_y$ implies $r_x \leq r_y$.

no, you could have $p_x>p_y$ and $r_x>r_y$. Example: x = {3,3,3}, y = {1,3,5}, then there are {2,2,2} and {4,4,4}.

@carlo Thanks for this answer, and SextusEmpiricus thanks for the helpful discussion in the comments. I like your suggestion of counting how many items are stochastically dominated by others. Even if it's not a total order and might not help much with choosing among moderately-good items, it seems like a reasonable way to find products that are among the "worst 10%" or "best 10%" -- which is what I need for my particular problem.

You may (or may not) need to consider total orders that respect the ordinal nature of your measurement
There is some variation in practice over how to treat measures like the Likert scale and what kind of summary measures are appropriate for distributions on this scale.  The Likert scale is typically regarded as an example of an ordinal measurement where the numerical label is only informative of the order of the possible values (see this related question).  For an ordinal measurement the mean and the weighted mean are not invariant to changes in the numerical labels that do not affect the ordering, which means that the mean and the weighted mean are essentially arbitrary measurements.  This is a good reason to avoid ranking distributions of ordinal measurements by the mean or weighted mean if one wishes to respect the ordinal nature of the measurement.
On the other hand, there is an argument for the idea that measurement on a Likert scale is implicitly interval data, since those choosing the scale outcomes may implicitly interpret differences in the ordinal measurement as having a constant "distance" from one another.  Whether or not this is the case requires some judgment as to the way that results are measured on the scale (e.g., if they are survey results then you migth consider the likely thinking of survey respondents).  If one interprets the Likert scale as implicitly giving interval data then a measure like the mean (or weighted mean) becomes a legitimate measure.  The difficulty occurs in making a judgment that there are known (e.g., equivalent) "distances" between adjacent outcomes in the scale.  The greater the confidence that there are implicit "distances" that are roughly equal, the greater the confidence in the mean as a legitimate aggregation summary.

Aggregation measures for ordinal data: For ordinal data, stochastic dominance is only a partial order on the set of all ordinal distributions but lexicographic dominance gives a total order on the set of all ordinal distributions.  The latter is quite an extreme ordering, and it is not a particularly good aggregation measure unless there is a reason to focus exclusively on ordering of individual categories in a particular order (with later categories used only as tie-breakers).  There are also many other total orders that could be constructed that would respect the general idea of rating in a manner that punishes lower ratings.  Ultimately, the choice of ordering will require some decision on the trade-offs between variations in ratings (e.g., some lower ratings and some higher ratings).  Lexicographic ordering is very narrow and gives consideration of only one rating category at a time, so you might prefer to use an ordering that allows more holistic consideration of ratings across categories.
Aggregation measures for interval data: For interval data, one may form legitimate aggregation measures as linear functions of the probabilities in each category.  This opens up the use of the mean or weighted mean as an aggregation measure, which is a useful way to rank distributions in terms of their central location.  Means are commonly used for ranking of central location for interval data, but you also have the option of weighting particular categories more heavily if you wish to do so.

"so you might prefer to use an ordering that allows more holistic consideration of ratings across categories" maybe suggest some. I don't agree that the arithmetic mean would be a worse measure than lexicographic dominance in any but very particular scenarios (app ratings not one of them).

The point is not whether Likert scales really provide interval data or not, but rather whether summarising a distribution of Likert scores by its mean, say, is deemed appropriate in the given situation. When it comes to invariance against monotonic transformations, fair enough we can't say that the "true" difference between Likert 2 and 3  is the same as between 4 and 5, but it would certainly not do the data justice to score five levels, say, 0-1-123.4-123.5-$10^{10}$, so it's rather irrelevant that the mean would screw up in that case.

For example (a point made by @NickCox already in comments to the question), sure, the mean can be criticised on grounds that it implicitly uses interval information that the data don't back up, but still it is more sensitive than the median or other quantiles/lexicographical to certain differences between distributions that may be very relevant in the given application, and in the given application there may not be relevant examples where the mean can be argued to "get things wrong" (at least worse than available alternatives).

Based on comments, I have now softened this answer a bit to give a better idea of the range of practices.

@Ben I agree with the points made in your answer, but the only suggestions I see are ones I already made: mean, weighted mean, or lexicographic dominance. You write "There are also many other total orders" that could be useful here -- what are some of them?

First of all, a ranking is based on a binary order relationship. This requires that $C>B$ and $B>A$ leads to $C>A$. If this is not the case, for example when you have relationships like rock paper scissors, then you can not make a ranking based on comparisons with that relationship.
To make a ranking you can convert the multidimensional data e.g. the number of ratings in 5 categories into a one dimensional value $y = f(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)$ and rank based on the order in that value. How you do that depends on what different aspects/features you find important and how you weigh the different aspects.
More complex approaches would involve metadata about the values.
For example in an elo rating one counts the number of losses, draws and wins (which you could see like a 3-points scale), but also the elo ratings of the opponents at the time that a count is added is recorded in the rating score.
The value of certain features in a distribution may change in time and depending on what is around.
For such complex ratings it might be even possible to turn rock paper scissors style orders into a single ranking (a crude method here A multidimensional ELO rating with rock paper scissors playing styles: how to estimate). I believe that they call this meta in the trade card game Magic the Gathering. Certain types of card decks have specific advantages versus others like rock paper scissors, but based on the popularity and presence of the card decks being played in competitions, one could rank based on the win probability of a certain card deck.

So in short, you need a function that can convert the distribution into a single number, then rank based on the number.
That function could be a plain function based solely on the values of a single distribution. But it can also be complex and involve the properties of the sampling (like in a rating system one could involve the properties of the raters).

Thank you. I agree that y=f(...) is one approach to what I'm looking for, but are there generally-useful suggestions for this f besides the ones already in my question? Also, the suggestion to look at Elo ratings is intriguing, but I don't see a way to use that in my situation since I don't see head-to-head comparisons between items; I only see each item's 5-star ratings.

@civilstat as an alternative to the suggested elo rating when you have head to head comparisons, you could compute something similar to the stochastic dominance which is P(X>Y) where X is the distribution that you wan to score and Y is the average of all distributions.
